# android emulator not connecting to development REST web service ETIMEDOUT

Tags: android, rest, web, service, emulation

I have the following permissions in my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></user-permission>
```

I have tried localhost, did not work of course, but then I tried 10.0.2.2 and still not working. I'm getting the ETIMEDOUT error.

```
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
    try
    {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200)
        {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
```

It is failing at the httpClient.execute part

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add some more code so I can see what exactly fails but generally I think you need to add -

```
httpGet .setEntity("Some entity");
```

"Some entity" - should be the parameters you want to send or null in case you dont have any.

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't get it to work in IIS Express, but then hooked it up to IIS Local and it worked, go figure.